# TinyMCE Responsive file manager error on movie uploads

Tags: php, video, upload, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

I have installed last version of TinyMCE and Responsive file manager on my site. Everything is OK and work correctly. But when I want to upload movie files (.mp4 with 700KB size), after uploading, this error appears and uploading become stop.
Thumbnails creation: File extension is not allowed. (@/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/js/filemanager/upload.php#255).

This is my config.php file

```
<?php
//if (session_id() == '') session_start();
session_start();

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Optional security
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| if set to true only those will access RF whose url contains the access key(akey) like:
| <input type="button" href="../filemanager/dialog.php?field_id=imgField&lang=en_EN&akey=myPrivateKey" value="Files">
| in tinymce a new parameter added: filemanager_access_key:"myPrivateKey"
| example tinymce config:
|
| tiny init ...
| external_filemanager_path:"../filemanager/",
| filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
| filemanager_access_key:"myPrivateKey" ,
| ...
|
*/

define('USE_ACCESS_KEYS', false); // TRUE or FALSE

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DON'T COPY THIS VARIABLES IN FOLDERS config.php FILES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

define('DEBUG_ERROR_MESSAGE', true); // TRUE or FALSE

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Path configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| In this configuration the folder tree is
| root
|    |- source <- upload folder
|    |- thumbs <- thumbnail folder [must have write permission (755)]
|    |- filemanager
|    |- js
|    |   |- tinymce
|    |   |   |- plugins
|    |   |   |   |- responsivefilemanager
|    |   |   |   |   |- plugin.min.js
*/

$config = array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DON'T TOUCH (base url (only domain) of site).
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | without final / (DON'T TOUCH)
    |
    */
    'base_url' => ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ! in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']), array( 'off', 'no' ))) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | path from base_url to base of upload folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | with start and final /
    |
    */
    'upload_dir' => '/files/recruiter/'.md5(md5($_SESSION['UID'])).'/uploads/',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | with final /
    |
    */
    'current_path' => '../../files/recruiter/'.md5(md5($_SESSION['UID'])).'/uploads/',


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | with final /
    | DO NOT put inside upload folder
    |
    */
    'thumbs_base_path' => '../../files/recruiter/'.md5(md5($_SESSION['UID'])).'/thumbs/',


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FTP configuration BETA VERSION
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you want enable ftp use write these parametres otherwise leave empty
    | Remember to set base_url properly to point in the ftp server domain and 
    | upload dir will be ftp_base_folder + upload_dir so without final /
    |
    */
    'ftp_host'         => false,
    'ftp_user'         => "user",
    'ftp_pass'         => "pass",
    'ftp_base_folder'  => '/uploads',
    'ftp_base_url'     => 'http://xxx.xxx',
    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | path from ftp_base_folder to base of thumbs folder with start and final |
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    'ftp_thumbs_dir' => '/thumbs/',
    'ftp_ssl' => false,
    'ftp_port' => 21,


    // 'ftp_host'         => "s108707.gridserver.com",
    // 'ftp_user'         => "test@responsivefilemanager.com",
    // 'ftp_pass'         => "Test.1234",
    // 'ftp_base_folder'  => "/domains/responsivefilemanager.com/html",


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Access keys
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | add access keys eg: array('myPrivateKey', 'someoneElseKey');
    | keys should only containt (a-z A-Z 0-9 \ . _ -) characters
    | if you are integrating lets say to a cms for admins, i recommend making keys randomized something like this:
    | $username = 'Admin';
    | $salt = 'dsflFWR9u2xQa' (a hard coded string)
    | $akey = md5($username.$salt);
    | DO NOT use 'key' as access key!
    | Keys are CASE SENSITIVE!
    |
    */

    'access_keys' => array(),

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // YOU CAN COPY AND CHANGE THESE VARIABLES INTO FOLDERS config.php FILES TO CUSTOMIZE EACH FOLDER OPTIONS
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Maximum size of all files in source folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | in Megabytes
    |
    */
    'MaxSizeTotal' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Maximum upload size
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | in Megabytes
    |
    */
    'MaxSizeUpload' => 5,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File and Folder permission
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    */
    'fileFolderPermission' => 0755,


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | default language file name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'default_language' => "en_EN",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Icon theme
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Default available: ico and ico_dark
    | Can be set to custom icon inside filemanager/img
    |
    */
    'icon_theme' => "ico",


    //Show or not total size in filemanager (is possible to greatly increase the calculations)
    'show_total_size'                       => false,
    //Show or not show folder size in list view feature in filemanager (is possible, if there is a large folder, to greatly increase the calculations)
    'show_folder_size'                      => false,
    //Show or not show sorting feature in filemanager
    'show_sorting_bar'                      => true,
    //Show or not show filters button in filemanager
    'show_filter_buttons'                   => true,
    //Show or not language selection feature in filemanager
    'show_language_selection'               => true,
    //active or deactive the transliteration (mean convert all strange characters in A..Za..z0..9 characters)
    'transliteration'                       => false,
    //convert all spaces on files name and folders name with $replace_with variable
    'convert_spaces'                        => true,
    //convert all spaces on files name and folders name this value
    'replace_with'                          => "_",
    //convert to lowercase the files and folders name
    'lower_case'                            => false,

    //Add ?484899493349 (time value) to returned images to prevent cache
    'add_time_to_img'                       => false,

    // -1: There is no lazy loading at all, 0: Always lazy-load images, 0+: The minimum number of the files in a directory
    // when lazy loading should be turned on.
    'lazy_loading_file_number_threshold'    => 0,


    //*******************************************
    //Images limit and resizing configuration
    //*******************************************

    // set maximum pixel width and/or maximum pixel height for all images
    // If you set a maximum width or height, oversized images are converted to those limits. Images smaller than the limit(s) are unaffected
    // if you don't need a limit set both to 0
    'image_max_width'                         => 1024,
    'image_max_height'                        => 1000,
    'image_max_mode'                          => 'auto',
    /*
    #  $option:  0 / exact = defined size;
    #            1 / portrait = keep aspect set height;
    #            2 / landscape = keep aspect set width;
    #            3 / auto = auto;
    #            4 / crop= resize and crop;
    */

    //Automatic resizing //
    // If you set $image_resizing to TRUE the script converts all uploaded images exactly to image_resizing_width x image_resizing_height dimension
    // If you set width or height to 0 the script automatically calculates the other dimension
    // Is possible that if you upload very big images the script not work to overcome this increase the php configuration of memory and time limit
    'image_resizing'                          => false,
    'image_resizing_width'                    => 0,
    'image_resizing_height'                   => 0,
    'image_resizing_mode'                     => 'auto', // same as $image_max_mode
    'image_resizing_override'                 => false,
    // If set to TRUE then you can specify bigger images than $image_max_width & height otherwise if image_resizing is
    // bigger than $image_max_width or height then it will be converted to those values


    //******************
    //
    // WATERMARK IMAGE
    // 
    //Watermark url or false
    'image_watermark'                          => false,
    # Could be a pre-determined position such as:
    #           tl = top left,
    #           t  = top (middle),
    #           tr = top right,
    #           l  = left,
    #           m  = middle,
    #           r  = right,
    #           bl = bottom left,
    #           b  = bottom (middle),
    #           br = bottom right
    #           Or, it could be a co-ordinate position such as: 50x100
    'image_watermark_position'                 => 'br',
    # padding: If using a pre-determined position you can
    #         adjust the padding from the edges by passing an amount
    #         in pixels. If using co-ordinates, this value is ignored.
    'image_watermark_padding'                 => 0,

    //******************
    // Default layout setting
    //
    // 0 => boxes
    // 1 => detailed list (1 column)
    // 2 => columns list (multiple columns depending on the width of the page)
    // YOU CAN ALSO PASS THIS PARAMETERS USING SESSION VAR => $_SESSION['RF']["VIEW"]=
    //
    //******************
    'default_view'                            => 0,

    //set if the filename is truncated when overflow first row
    'ellipsis_title_after_first_row'          => true,

    //*************************
    //Permissions configuration
    //******************
    'delete_files'                            => true,
    'create_folders'                          => false,
    'delete_folders'                          => false,
    'upload_files'                            => true,
    'rename_files'                            => true,
    'rename_folders'                          => false,
    'duplicate_files'                         => false,
    'copy_cut_files'                          => false, // for copy/cut files
    'copy_cut_dirs'                           => false, // for copy/cut directories
    'chmod_files'                             => false, // change file permissions
    'chmod_dirs'                              => false, // change folder permissions
    'preview_text_files'                      => true, // eg.: txt, log etc.
    'edit_text_files'                         => false, // eg.: txt, log etc.
    'create_text_files'                       => false, // only create files with exts. defined in $editable_text_file_exts

    // you can preview these type of files if $preview_text_files is true
    'previewable_text_file_exts'              => array('pdf'),
    'previewable_text_file_exts_no_prettify'  => array(),

    // you can edit these type of files if $edit_text_files is true (only text based files)
    // you can create these type of files if $create_text_files is true (only text based files)
    // if you want you can add html,css etc.
    // but for security reasons it's NOT RECOMMENDED!
    'editable_text_file_exts'                 => array(),

    // Preview with Google Documents
    'googledoc_enabled'                       => false,
    'googledoc_file_exts'                     => array(),

    // Preview with Viewer.js
    'viewerjs_enabled'                        => true,
    'viewerjs_file_exts'                      => array('pdf'),

    // defines size limit for paste in MB / operation
    // set 'FALSE' for no limit
    'copy_cut_max_size'                       => 100,
    // defines file count limit for paste / operation
    // set 'FALSE' for no limit
    'copy_cut_max_count'                      => 200,
    //IF any of these limits reached, operation won't start and generate warning

    //**********************
    //Allowed extensions (lowercase insert)
    //**********************
    'ext_img'                                 => array('jpg','jpeg','png'), //Images
    'ext_file'                                => array('doc','docx','pdf','xls','xlsx','csv','ppt','pptx'), //Files
    'ext_video'                               => array('mpeg','mp4','flv','webm','mov'), //Video
    'ext_music'                               => array('mp3','ogg'), //Audio
    'ext_misc'                                => array('ico'), //Archives

    /******************
    * AVIARY config
    *******************/
    'aviary_active'                           => true,
    'aviary_apiKey'                           => "2444282ef4344e3dacdedc7a78f8877d",
    'aviary_language'                         => "en",
    'aviary_theme'                            => "light",
    'aviary_tools'                            => "all",
    'aviary_maxSize'                          => "1400",
    // Add or modify the Aviary options below as needed - they will be json encoded when added to the configuration so arrays can be utilized as needed

    //The filter and sorter are managed through both javascript and php scripts because if you have a lot of
    //file in a folder the javascript script can't sort all or filter all, so the filemanager switch to php script.
    //The plugin automatic swich javascript to php when the current folder exceeds the below limit of files number
    'file_number_limit_js'                    => 500,

    //**********************
    // Hidden files and folders
    //**********************
    // set the names of any folders you want hidden (eg "hidden_folder1", "hidden_folder2" ) Remember all folders with these names will be hidden (you can set any exceptions in config.php files on folders)
    'hidden_folders'                          => array(),
    // set the names of any files you want hidden. Remember these names will be hidden in all folders (eg "this_document.pdf", "that_image.jpg" )
    'hidden_files'                            => array( 'config.php' ),

    /*******************
    * JAVA upload
    *******************/
    'java_upload'                             => true,
    'JAVAMaxSizeUpload'                       => 1, //Gb


    //************************************
    //Thumbnail for external use creation
    //************************************


    // New image resized creation with fixed path from filemanager folder after uploading (thumbnails in fixed mode)
    // If you want create images resized out of upload folder for use with external script you can choose this method,
    // You can create also more than one image at a time just simply add a value in the array
    // Remember than the image creation respect the folder hierarchy so if you are inside source/test/test1/ the new image will create at
    // path_from_filemanager/test/test1/
    // PS if there isn't write permission in your destination folder you must set it
    //
    'fixed_image_creation'                    => false, //activate or not the creation of one or more image resized with fixed path from filemanager folder
    'fixed_path_from_filemanager'             => array( '../test/', '../test1/' ), //fixed path of the image folder from the current position on upload folder
    'fixed_image_creation_name_to_prepend'    => array( '', 'test_' ), //name to prepend on filename
    'fixed_image_creation_to_append'          => array( '_test', '' ), //name to appendon filename
    'fixed_image_creation_width'              => array( 300, 400 ), //width of image (you can leave empty if you set height)
    'fixed_image_creation_height'             => array( 200, '' ), //height of image (you can leave empty if you set width)
    /*
    #             $option:     0 / exact = defined size;
    #                          1 / portrait = keep aspect set height;
    #                          2 / landscape = keep aspect set width;
    #                          3 / auto = auto;
    #                          4 / crop= resize and crop;
    */
    'fixed_image_creation_option'             => array( 'crop', 'auto' ), //set the type of the crop


    // New image resized creation with relative path inside to upload folder after uploading (thumbnails in relative mode)
    // With Responsive filemanager you can create automatically resized image inside the upload folder, also more than one at a time
    // just simply add a value in the array
    // The image creation path is always relative so if i'm inside source/test/test1 and I upload an image, the path start from here
    //
    'relative_image_creation'                 => false, //activate or not the creation of one or more image resized with relative path from upload folder
    'relative_path_from_current_pos'          => array( './', './' ), //relative path of the image folder from the current position on upload folder
    'relative_image_creation_name_to_prepend' => array( '', '' ), //name to prepend on filename
    'relative_image_creation_name_to_append'  => array( '_thumb', '_thumb1' ), //name to append on filename
    'relative_image_creation_width'           => array( 300, 400 ), //width of image (you can leave empty if you set height)
    'relative_image_creation_height'          => array( 200, '' ), //height of image (you can leave empty if you set width)
    /*
    #             $option:     0 / exact = defined size;
    #                          1 / portrait = keep aspect set height;
    #                          2 / landscape = keep aspect set width;
    #                          3 / auto = auto;
    #                          4 / crop= resize and crop;
    */
    'relative_image_creation_option'          => array( 'crop', 'crop' ), //set the type of the crop


    // Remember text filter after close filemanager for future session
    'remember_text_filter'                    => false,

);

return array_merge(
    $config,
    array(
        'MaxSizeUpload' => ((int)(ini_get('post_max_size')) < $config['MaxSizeUpload'])
            ? (int)(ini_get('post_max_size')) : $config['MaxSizeUpload'],
        'ext'=> array_merge(
            $config['ext_img'],
            $config['ext_file'],
            $config['ext_misc'],
            $config['ext_video'],
            $config['ext_music']
        ),
        // For a list of options see: https://developers.aviary.com/docs/web/setup-guide#constructor-config
        'aviary_defaults_config' => array(
            'apiKey'     => $config['aviary_apiKey'],
            'language'   => $config['aviary_language'],
            'theme'      => $config['aviary_theme'],
            'tools'      => $config['aviary_tools'],
            'maxSize'    => $config['aviary_maxSize']
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved !! I added 'mp4'=>'video/mp4' to the MIME types array in filemanager/include/mime_type_lib.php. It works correctly now.